# How can super() instantiate a class inside it's own __new__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently had a use case for a singleton class and ended up using this definition:

```
class SubClient(BaseClient):

    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(SubClient, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance
```

After testing that this worked, some questions came up:

How is it possible that `super(SubClient, cls).__new__(cls)` returns an instance of `SubClient` within the definition of the `SubClient.__new__` method?

`__new__` is the method that creates a `SubClient` so how is it possible that within the definition of this method we can already create a `SubClient` ?

Comment: `super(SubClient, cls)` is calling `BaseClient.__new__`: that's the superclass of `SubClient`.

Comment: but then isn't cls.instance is a BaseClient and not a SubClient?

Comment: @JorgeLuis The question is why that results in an instance of `SubClient` and not `BaseClient`

Comment: @jhnclvr: No, because it's passing `cls` to the superclass method.

Comment: `SubClient(...)` causes `BaseClient.__new__(Subclient, ...)` to be called. A different subclass of of `BaseClient` like `Foo` would cause `BaseClient.__new__(Foo, ...)` to be called.

Comment: Also note that `SubClient.__new__` only returns an instance of `SubClient` if that's what it's defined to return; nothing about it *inherently* returns an instance of `SubClient.` In fact, you could just return `3` and that would be legal. `type.__call__` (which is what causes `__new__` to be called) actually checks the return value of `__new__` to determine if its `__init__` method should be called: `SubClient.__init___` is only called automatically when `SubClient.__new__` does, in fact, return an instance of `SubClient`.

Comment: @chepner Ok that makes sense, but then it must be possible to create an instance of SubClient without calling its `__new__` method. I don't quite understand why  `super(SubClient, cls).__new__(cls)` doesn't call the `__new__` method of SubClient (causing infinite recursion)? Since it's not doing that how is it creating an object of type SubClient? Does it just create the parent class and then `parent.type = subtype` (or something) ?

Comment: Because that's not what `super` does. `super(SubClient, cls).__new__` uses the MRO of `cls` to look for a definition of `__new__`, starting with the class *after* `SubClient`. If it finds `BaseClient.__new__`, it uses that. If that's not defined, it looks further. Since `__new__` isn't commonly overriden, *usually* you end up with `object.__new__`.

Comment: @chepner ok thanks, I finally get how this is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* way to create a new object is to call `object.__new__`. When you override `__new__`, the intent is to either return some other pre-existing object, or to use `super` to get an ancestor class to provide an object.

Note that `__new__` is a *static* method that's special-cased so that you don't have to decorate it with `@staticmethod`. `object.__new__` does not necessarily create an instance of `object`: `object.__new__(foo)` creates a new object of type `foo`, whatever `foo` might be. That's why you need to explicitly pass the `cls` value as the first argument, rather than just being able to write `super(SubClient, cls).__new__()`.

---

Beware of using `__new__` like this to implement the singleton design pattern. When you call `SubClient(...)`, it uses `SubClient.__new__` to get an instance of `SubClient`. As long as `SubClient.instance` is an instance of `SubClient`, it *will* invoke `cls.instance.__init__` again, even though it was initialized when first created. This is at best inefficient and unnecessary, at worst an unexpected reinitiization of an object that you didn't expect.

Consider this code:

```
class A:
    instance = None

    def __init__(self, x):
        print("In __init__")
        self.x = x

    def __new__(cls, x):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance


a1 = A(3)
a1.x = 5
a2 = A(9)
assert a1 is a2
assert a1.x == 9  # Not 5
```

Two calls to `A`, *one* call to `object.__new__`, but two calls to `A.instance.__init__` on the same object. Calling `A(9)` returns the same instance that `a1` refers to, but causes it to be reinitialized, overwriting the previous change to `a1.x` made by `a1.x = 5`.

Instead of overriding `__new__` use an explicit class method to access the class attribute.

```
class A:
    instance = None

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @classmethod
    def get_it(cls, x):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = cls(x)
        return cls.instance

a1 = A.get_it(3)
```

Whether it makes sense for a function that returns a singleton to be parameterized in the first place is a question for another time. If it makes sense to parameterize, you may want a *memoized* function rather than a singleton (which is in some sense a special case of memoization).

Comment: Contrary to what is implied here, you don’t actually have to declare static methods with `@staticmethod` (though it is good practice). All `@staticmethod` does is prevent binding the first parameter when the method is accessed on an instance.

Comment: [`__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such)...](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

Comment: If you don't decorate the function at all, it will be an instance method, *but* if you access the attribute from the class rather than an instance, you'll get the underlying function, just like `staticmethod.__get__` provides whether you access the value from the class or an instance of the class.

Comment: @chepner regarding multiple calls to `__init__` I noticed this when running some tests and using the debugger so I changed `__init__` to compensate for this. It's not the prettiest thing, so I'm wondering which way you recommend to implement a singleton?

Comment: I'll update the answer with one approach.